# How to run JQuery in a JavaScript function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a dynamic function but i am having trouble because i cant seem to run my JQuery code inside of a JS function. I have a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UpEvK/1/).

I have a second example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UpEvK/). the only difference between the two JsFiddle's is that i switched the call function from:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
```

to this calling function:

```
function addBtn(){
```

and the same on the delBtn. the reason i want to do this is so i can pass an argument so i know if i want to add another question  field or an answer  field.

Comment: How to run JQuery in a JavaScript function

Comment: It's just like every javascript code... jQuery is abstraction above Javascript, not some sort of magic.

Comment: ` var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);` should be  `var newNum = num + 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jsFiddle wraps the JavaScript code inside a closure by default (i.e. the functions are private variables). You have to choose "no wrap (body)": http://jsfiddle.net/UpEvK/2/.

Comment: o, i didnt realize this was a jsFiddle issue. I was frustrated cuz i didn't see any issues with it. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The two code snippets you provided are functionally different.

This is actually registering the click event:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function)
```

In this case 'function' is just a callback function, the name of the function you want called when the click event is fired. So to work with your second JS fiddle you would have to do the following:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(addBtn);
```

If you can give us a little more information about what you are actually trying to do with the code we may be able to provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that you added the onclick attribute in the html in your second JSFidle, pimvdb's answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

I would get that code out of the markup.  You can use:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
   addBtn();
});
```

NOW since you have multiple: put a class='btnAdd' in the markup NOT the onclick handler and use:

```
$('.btnAdd').live('click',function() {
   addBtn();
});
```

the new markup:

```
<input class="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add Question" />
```

EDIT: now the FINAL SCRIPT to support both:

```
$('.btnAdd,#btnAdd').live('click',function() {
    addBtn();
});
```

NOTE FOR 1.7.1 jQuery users; use:

```
$(document).on('click','.btnAdd,#btnAdd',function() {
    addBtn();
});
```